# How can I write an UFT8 encoded file in LibreOffice?

Tags: utf-8, libreoffice

I would like to write an UFT8 encoded text file with LibreOffice Basic.

The example here http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Structure_of_Text_Documents#Example:_simple_HTML_export shows the use of the regular text writing

```
 Filename = "c:\temp\text.html"
 FileNo = Freefile
 Open Filename For Output As #FileNo   
 Print #FileNo, "<html><body>"
```

I traverse a document paragraph by paragraph and within paragraphs text element by text element

```
 Enum2 = TextElement.createEnumeration
 While Enum2.hasMoreElements
     TextPortion = Enum2.nextElement
     ...
 Wend
```

Depending on the findings document content is written to the text HTML file.

However Unicode characters are not written. Is it possible to enable UFT8 character writing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround is to convert all Unicode characters to NCRs first. Then it does not matter that the PRINT command does not deal with Unicode.

```
' search and replace Unicode values with NCRs (Numerical Character References)
' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NCR

Dim oDoc,aFind,aReplace,aRayCount,oFandR

    oDoc = thisComponent

    aFind = Array("Ɛ","ɛ","Ɔ","ɔ","Ŋ","ŋ")
    aReplace = Array("&#x190;","&#x25B;","&#x186;","&#x254;","&#x14A;","&#x14B;")
    index = 0

    oFandR = oDoc.createReplaceDescriptor
    oFandR.SearchCaseSensitive = true
    oFandR.SearchRegularExpression = false
    While index <= uBound(aFind)
        oFandR.setSearchString(aFind(index))
        oFandR.setReplaceString(aReplace(index))
        index = index + 1
        oDoc.ReplaceAll(oFandR)
    Wend
End Sub
```

Adapted from

http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=2437